# SVN reposiory using a TimeCapsule folder

Tags: svn

I will create an SVN repository using like Destination Folder a folder on TimeCapsule.
When I have tried to execute svn import destination-folder /Volumes/Data/... -m "Initial Import" it tell me: svn: Invalid URL '/Volumes/Data/....
Someone have tried to do the same thing successfully?
I have made a mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using TimeCapsule as location of repository is good idea

You have to read `svn help import` about correct format of this command

`svn import [PATH] URL`

Last parameter is **URL of repo** (with one of supported by Subversion protocols), for local-accessible repository (which must already exist) you **must** to use `file:///` protocol, not pure path

Comment: I know that is not the better way, but at the moment i will try something in order to generate an internal working network with shard folder and repository. I'll try your suggestion.